# Wall Textures In Different US States

Tags: walls, texture

I am trying to learn about wall textures. 
Can someone share some knowledge about in which US states are textured walls (like orange peel, ....) common vs which states they are not common?
I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement.  HI is modeled around questions with a specific answer.  Questions that act like a poll or attract a list are generally not a good fit.  Voting on the best answers becomes difficult because no answer is complete, and you can't accept one answer as the best.  As written, your question could attract 50 answers, each reflecting a different state.  The same goes for questions seeking general knowledge on a subject area (too broad), or requests for where to find resources (quickly outdated).  Can you think about how to reframe the question to better fit the site?

Answer (score 1):

Orange peel, knockdown and skip trowel finishes are very popular in FL. Faux finishing adds a nice touch.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I've observed:

Textured drywall was a feature of new homes from the 60s to the 90s.  Most of the population growth occurred in southern and western states during that time, and a large percentage of the new homes were built in those states.

Hence those finishes comprise a larger than average percentage of the housing stock in those states.  This is not to say you won't find these finishes in northeastern or midwestern states -- they also had new developments, but they are far less common in pre 1960s houses which comprise a larger percentage of the housing units in those states.